# How can I group_by and sum values in a data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dfply

I have this data frame (please refer the figure below)

```
| State        | County        |  Homicides
|--------------|---------------|-----------
|   Ags        |  Calvillo     |    4
|  Mexico City |  Alvaro O     |    2
|  Mexico City | Alvaro O      |    3
|  Mexico City |  Miguel H     |    2
|   Gto        |   Leon        |    1
|   Gto        |   Leon        |    1
```

What I want to do is group by County and sum the value of homicides. for example

```
| State        | County        |  Homicides
|--------------|---------------|-----------
|   Ags        |  Calvillo     |    4
|  Mexico City |  Alvaro O     |    5
| Mexico City  |  Miguel H     |    2
|   Gto        |   Leon        |    2
```

As you can see I summarize the values of homicides with the same county name

This was my attempt

```
df1 >> group_by("County") >> summarize(County = X.County)
```

But is not doing what I Want, can someone guide me with this question, please.

Thanks

Comment: `df.group_by("County").agg('sum')`

Comment: Thank you! But what about with my column State, this answer is grouping by county but gives me just the column "County" and "Homicides" how can I recover my column "State"?

Comment: You'll have to add it to the `group_by`

Comment: df.groupby(["State",'County']).agg('sum'), Yes I tried this but is only giving me one unique state in the column "State" and if I have one state with different county I want to keep the state with the county not just one unique state

Answer (score 0):

With your help this was my last line of codes that help me with this issue

```
df1 = df1.groupby(['State',"County"]).agg('sum')
df1 =df1.reset_index()
df1
```

This was my result

```
| State        | County        |  Homicides
|--------------|---------------|-----------
|   Ags        |  Calvillo     |    4
|  Mexico City |  Alvaro O     |    5
| Mexico City  |  Miguel H     |    2
|   Gto        |   Leon        |    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same struggle to do group_by & summation with dfply. Description of "dfply" module for using group_by function in https://github.com/kieferk/dfply/blob/master/README.md is not enough, I think.

Try below.

```
df1 >> group_by(X.Country) >> summarize(sum_Country = X.County.sum())
```